# Implementation of a program to carry out floating point calculations every 25ms using a linux signal handler in a multi-threaded server program?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

My Aim: I need to calculate new control inputs of my system and update the position of the robot I am programming at precise sampling instants.

Problem background: I have a functioning server program that services multiple clients and can do simple robot maneuvers. To do this I have two threads, one to control the robot and one to service the multiple clients. Now I need to implement more complex swarm algorithms at precise sample instants. I have successfully written a side program (using setitimer() ) that interrupts every 25ms using SIGVTALRM.

Now I need advice on how is best to proceed design wise. My main worry is how to execute the algorithm in the signal handler since it has to satisy many constraints due to multi-threads and signal safe functions.

Sorry for the long explanation, but I feel a good explanation will produce a good answer.

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: How precise does the timing need to be? +- 1ms? +- 10ms?

Comment: +- 0.1ms would be good enough.

Comment: Have you looked at `timer_create` and `timer_settime`?

Comment: I have read about them briefly, but not looked into them in detail. Do they have any particular advantage over the setitimer() method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, doing any sort of work in a signal handler is irritating. To avoid the irritation, I would spawn another thread (if you have the space for it), and have that thread wait on a semaphore. You can then post to that semaphore from your signal handler to wake up your processing thread.

This would still be subject to jitter from the scheduler, and I'm not sure (without doing some testing) whether that's going to be able to satisfy your 100us deadline, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Very Helpful! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I concur that performing work in signal handler is to be avoided, particularly in a multithreaded application.  There is very little you can safely do in an async-signal environment in POSIX.

I would avoid using signals at all: you can simply spawn a thread that waits for the next deadline before performing the necessary work, then loops around to wait again:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *timed_calculation_thread(void *ptr)
{
    struct timespec deadline;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &deadline);

    while(1)
    {
        /* Perform floating point calculations, update robot state
         * etc. here */

        /* Add 25ms to previous deadline */
        deadline.tv_nsec += 25000000;
        deadline.tv_sec += deadline.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
        deadline.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;
        /* Sleep until new deadline */
        while (clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL) != 0)
            if (errno != EINTR) return NULL;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

If your process runs with sufficient privileges you can also give this thread a realtime scheduling class, if necessary.

In practice this can give you quite good latency results.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out and let you know :) !